# Wordpress CSS flex-direction issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox

I'm setting page for my friend, but I have a small issue.
http://spiratree.wp.hehe.si [Home page]

After several hours of searching I still can’t find the solutions.
Below is a picture showing how I made banners with SPB section (WP-plugin): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q3qz.jpg - Picture 01 [on bigger screen]

My wish is that for mobile devices site would stacked like:
Picture 02 [on mobile devices]

I was try using code:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

First I created row-s with SPB Section and added Extra class “rev-col” Picture 03

Then I added in the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .rev-col {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
}
```

However, it does not do anything. I tried manually to enter the code and it works: Picture 04

Maybe you know what is the solution of my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."  Adding links to external websites usually gets classified as spam and the question is closed.

Comment: I understand that attaching external link is not desirable. However, my problem is so specific that the problem is not easily solved without access to the code.

Simply because I do not know which part of the code used in CSS that will be recognized on page.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because after viewing the link - the problem that was trying to be solved no longer exists and there is not enough code to be helpful to future visitors.